# Combine 2 conditions in regex

Tags: javascript, java, regex, string, match

I wanted to create a regex that checks for non ASCII characters and some special characters.

```
 /^[\x00-\x7F]+$/  

 '[^{}$]*'
```

The conditions are working individually, but not when I combine them. Tried with

```
/^([\x00-\x7F]|[^{}$]*)$/   but failing.
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing `+` in the first part of combination, `/^([\x00-\x7F]+|[^{}$]*)$/`

Comment: Extend the first alternate group to include the special characters

Comment: how can I extend that?

Comment: Please add few examples of valid and invalid matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^[\x00-\x7F]+$` - matches a string completely composed of ASCII characters.

`[^{}$]*`  matches zero or more characters different from `{`, `}` and `$`.

So, the second rule matches any string. If that is your intent, just use the first regular expression.

If you want to match any ASCII only string, excluding `{`, `}` and `$` use

```
^(?=[\x00-\x7F]+$)[^{}$]*$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Hz9wVm/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\x00-\x7F]+             any character of: '\x00' to '\x7F' (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^{}$]*                  any character except: '{', '}', '$' (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is something wrong with the this `[\x00-\x7F]` part of your regex. I've tried the following and it works.

`^([[:ascii:]]+$|[^{}$]*)$`